# Does DalekJS support https?

Tags: https, dalekjs

Just a quick question --
Does DalekJS support https?

I've been to http://dalekjs.com/pages/getStarted.html, and the demo only uses http, 
even the http://dalekjs.com/pages/documentation.html is not clear about that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use dalek with https:

```
.open('https://yourapp.com/signin')
```